# Recursing through a List is not updating objects as expected

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to recurse through a bunch of GameObjects in a list:

```
// get the relative position of the weapons to the ship
List<Transform> weaponPositions = ship.GetWeaponLocations(); // works

// set the positions of the weapons
for(int i = 0 ; i < equippedWeapons.Length && i < weaponPositions.Count ; i++)       
{
    equippedWeapons[i].GetComponent<Weapon>().setPosition(weaponPositions[i]);
}
```

However it seems to apply the last 'weaponPositions' to everything. So weaponPositions is a list of type Transform, and I want to set the position of weapon[0] to the position of weaponPosition[0] for example.

The problem is that when it gets to the third weapon (the last in this case), it applies the weaponPosition[2] position to each of the weapons that has come before, not just the i'th index.

The weapons are a SerailizedField:

```
[SerializeField] GameObject[] equippedWeapons;
```

In weapon the setWeapon method is simply:

```
Transform positionOfWeaponOnShip;

public void setPosition(Transform pos)
{
    positionOfWeaponOnShip = pos;
}
```

The question I am asking is, am I using the List in the correct way here? Im stumped as to why it isnt only applying this to the i'th value. Im also not sure what else I can put here which would be useful...

Thanks, 
Bogo

Comment: Try adding a Debug.Log("currentPosition is: " + weaponPositions[i]); inside the for loop and before the assignment. Check the log to see if the positions are correct

Comment: (1) Check whether `GetComponent<Weapon>()` is returning the same reference when called on all objects in `equippedWeapons`; (2) Check whether all objects in `weaponPositions` are actually the same.

Comment: Hmm, the instance IDs are all the same... does that means when I drag and drop a prefab into the [SerializeField] it uses the same prefab for each, as opposed to making a new instance for each element in the list? As a test I duplicated the weapon prefab three times and put them all in separately and then yes, it works perfectly. But I dont want that, I want my one prefab weapon to have multiple instances of if dropped into the equippedweapons field...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem it seems was that each reference was to the same prefab, and not an instance of that prefab.

To solve this, when launching the weapons script, I instantiate a new version of that weapon as opposed to referring to the prefab. This now works :)

Thanks for the help!
Bogo

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the transforms position, you have to change the `positionOfWeaponOnShip.position` not the `positionOfWeaponOnShip`. I hope this helps you!

```
Transform positionOfWeaponOnShip;
public void setPosition(Transform pos)
{
    positionOfWeaponOnShip.position = new Vector3(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but the variable in the Weapon is a Transform, not a Position.

Comment: You got on the right path but the type of the parameter should be Vector3 or assign pos.position

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to assign a new Transform to the object which is not possible. Every object in Unity is given a Transform by default that you can't remove. It's the sole component that every single game object has to have.

You cannot assign a new Transform to a game object but you can assign a new position to a game object.

```
 // works but the method naming is inappropriate
 // Either the list should be Vector3 or the method should be named GetWeaponTransform
 List<Transform> weaponPositions = ship.GetWeaponLocations(); 

// if we stick with a collection of Transform
for(int i = 0 ; i < equippedWeapons.Length && i < weaponPositions.Count ; i++)       
{
    equippedWeapons[i].GetComponent<Weapon>().setPosition(weaponPositions[i].position); // added .position
}
```

Finally:

```
Transform transformOfWeaponOnShip;

public void setPosition(Vector3 pos)
{
    transformOfWeaponOnShip.position = pos;
}
```